# VUEX: Vuetify Expansion panel slot doesn't update after add an item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a data table made using Vuetify. When a user clicks in an item (the row), it shows an expansion panel with updates about the item where users can add new updates.

The expansion panel have a button which users click when they want to add a new update. The button activates a dialog with a form. Users input the info and then click in the save button which calls a mutations to add the new update.

The mutation actually works, but when I close the dialog, the info doesn't appear in the expansion panel.

The functions are the following:

**DashboardExpansionPanel.vue**

```
...
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        getItems: 'details/items',
        loading: 'details/loading',
        error: 'details/error'
    }),
    items() {
        return this.getItems(this.offerTransformer);
    }
},
methods: {
    ...mapActions({
        addDetail: 'details/add'
    }),
    save() {
        const data = {...this.editedItem, product_id: this.product};
        this.addDetail(data);
    }
  }
}
```

**details.module.js**

```
...
const initialState = {
    requesting: false,
    error: false,
    errMsg: ''
};
export const details = { 
    actions: {
        add({ dispatch, commit}, payload) {
            commit('detailRequest');
            const options = {...} // this is not important right now
            apiService.postRequest('details', payload, options)
            .then(data => {
                dispatch('entities/add', {...data , entity: 'details'}, { root: true });
                commit('detailSuccess');
            },
            err => {
                commit('detailsError', err);
            }
            );
        }
    },
    ...
    getters: {
        loading: state => state.requesting,
        error: state => state.error,
        items: (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) => (productID) => {
        const product = rootGetters['entities/getEntityById']('products', productID);
        return product.details.map((key) => (rootGetters['entities/getEntityById']('details', key)));
    }
    }
...
```

**entities.module.js**

```
...
mutations: {
    update(state, entities) {
        state = _.merge(state, entities);
    },
    add(state, { result, entities , entity }) {
       // Data is normalize using normalizr
        Vue.set(state[entity], result, entities[entity][result]);

        if(entity === 'details') {
            state.products[entities.details[result].productId].details.push(result);
        }
    }
},
getters: {
    getEntityById: (state) => (entity, id) => {
        return state[entity][id];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
This happen when the Product doesn't have details. In other words, when the length of details array of products is zero. When the product have a previous detail, it show the newly update added

**UPDATE 2**

**DashboardExpansionPanel.vue (template)**

```
<template>
    <div class="expand--slot pa-3">
    <v-data-table class="details-table" :headers="headers" :items="items" hide-actions>
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <td>{{ props.item.quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.codes || "Codes not assign yet" }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.guide || "Guide not assign yet" }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.deliveryOn || "Not delivered yet" }}</td>
            <td><pre>{{ props.item.status || "Without more info..." }}</pre></td>
            <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
             <v-icon small class="mr-3" @click="editItem(props.item)">edit</v-icon>
             <v-icon small @click="deleteItem(props.item)">delete</v-icon>
         </td>
     </template>
     <template slot="no-data">
        We are sorry, there's not information about this product :(
    </template>
...
```

Comment: Can you show how you are consuming the `getter` for the item that is saved?

Comment: @DanielOrmeño the `items` property is linked to the data table inside the expansion panel in the property `:items="items"`

Comment: Can you please update the question with the template? if you are certain that the mutation happens, I suspect is related to the way you are doing your bindings with Vue. i.e. not providing keys to the list.

Comment: Also, it looks like your mutation is asynchronous, you might want to use `async await` for this.

Comment: @DanielOrmeño sure! the mutation is done as I could see in the state (using Vue Development tool). On the other hand, I don't think mutation is asynchronous because I dispatch the action after I receive the information. Let me show some piece of code because template is really large